# Android GUI looks different when using margin and padding

Tags: android, android-layout, padding, android-xml, margins

I'm a beginner on Android, but my question require a little bit knowledge in UI and not in programming.
I have an xml code, i have their some views but for this question only two components are relevant.
The component is a **ScrollView** "father" that has only one "son" that is a **TextView**.
When setting *padding* in ScrollView, if the text inside the **TextView** is long, first line of **TextView** is a little bit truncated (although i am using padding). **But on the other hand**, when using *margin_layout* text is seen fine. I read a lot on the difference between *margin* and *padding* and from what i have understand setting *padding* inside *father* should give the same affect as setting *margin* inside son. I emphasize that i'm using only one son.
Code with margin (where text is fine):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Hello There this is where we are going to add something..."
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/true_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prev_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/false_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/next_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/true_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/previous_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
        android:text="@string/counter_questions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code with padding (where first line is truncated)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Hello There this is where we are going to add something..."
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/true_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prev_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/false_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/next_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/true_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/previous_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
        android:text="@string/counter_questions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In addition, putting padding inside CardLayout make thins to be even bad than when adding padding inside the ScrollView

Can someone explain me the reason?

Comment: Did i make something wrong or the level of android experts is low?

Comment: @DorBak, why are you putting that `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`? It somehow looks like you don't need to.

Comment: It's a trivia game :) , sometimes question(string) are too long and bigger from the TextView. Why should i do instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the difference related to **ScrollView** odd behavior. I fixed the issue by setting *android:fillViewport="true"*, and removing *padding* and *margin_layout*